# How to getText from edittext contained in tablerow

Tags: android, sql, gettext, tablelayout, tablerow

Hi i use TableLyout to display data from my database (baza_kosztorys),i contain date from three columns (kosztorys_id, kosztorys_nazwa, inwestor) in tablerow (wiersz), i added button(przycisk) also and i put kosztorys_id as setText. Later i can gettext from button when i clicked on it(it works good), but i'd like to clik tablerow and gettext from edittext, without using button.

And it's a problem because gettext(kosztorys_id) from edittext it's not working the same as button, so how i can gettext from edittext when i click tablerow ??

my code.

```
package com.kosztorys;

import android.app.Activity;

public class NowePomieszczenie extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    String Timie, Tnazwisko, Tmail;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TextView textview1,textview2,textview3, textview4, textview5;
    Button przycisk;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nowe_pomieszczenie);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("baza_kosztorys", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }

public void pokazdane(View v)
  {

    final Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from kosztorys", null);
    int count= c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    //definicja wygladu

    final TableLayout wyglad = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    wyglad.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    //definicja wiersza
    TableRow wiersz = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

    //dodanie napisu id nad kolumna id
    TextView textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview.setText("DOSTĘPNE KOSZTORYSY");
    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textview.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    wiersz.addView(textview);

    wyglad.addView(wiersz);
       for(Integer j=0; j<count; j++)
         {
           wiersz = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
           wiersz.setClickable(true);


          textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
              textview.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kosztorys_id")));   
              textview2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
              textview2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kosztorys_nazwa")));
          textview3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
              textview3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("inwestor")));


                  przycisk = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                  przycisk.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kosztorys_id")));
                  wiersz.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kosztorys_id")));




         przycisk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                //v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);    
                 Button przycisk = (Button)v;
                    String buttonText = przycisk.getText().toString();
                    setContentView(R.layout.nowe_pomieszczenie);
                //    String buttonText2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("kosztorys_id"));
                 Toast.makeText(NowePomieszczenie.this, "wybrales kosztorys nr:"+buttonText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });

          wiersz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  

                }       
            });       
         //textview.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
           textview2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
           textview3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
           przycisk.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

           wiersz.addView(textview);
           wiersz.addView(textview2);
           wiersz.addView(textview3);
               wiersz.addView(przycisk);
           wyglad.addView(wiersz);

           c.moveToNext();
         }
         setContentView(wyglad);
         db.close();

  }
```

Comment: put the gettext in the wiersz on click?

Comment: Yes i trying but it's not working. I don't know how i can refer to edit text from wiersz.onClickListener() [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2owvk3oscl2cyp8/Zrzut%20ekranu%202013-11-10%2023.30.21.png)

Answer (score 0):

in the .xml folder of your activity, you can make the row call your method when it's clicked using android:onClick="Pokazdane".

Comment: Ofc i'm using, but it's not a problem, problem is how i can gettext from edittext from table row, this is my attempts to do that, but it not work [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2owvk3oscl2cyp8/Zrzut%20ekranu%202013-11-10%2023.30.21.png)

Comment: You should use the onlick on the text view not on the rowTabel

Comment: ok, but it'll work when i clik on textview not tablerow. I'd like to click on tablerow and get text from edittext/textview

Comment: you can use: (TextView)row.getChildAt(X); to access it